# Storing run configuration in Git

Tags: intellij-idea

Developers have many run configurations in IntelliJ IDEA storred in .idea/workspace.xml

Dilemma: Should I include workspace.xml in Git?

No ->  Defeats the purpose of source control
Yes -> Do I create a branch for every developer? Do I save it as workspace_developer_name.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which files in .idea folder should be tracked by Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198273/which-files-in-idea-folder-should-be-tracked-by-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Intellij documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#share-configurations), just enable the Store as project file option, and specify the location where the configuration file will be stored.

This is within the Run Debug Configurations window (Run | Edit Configurations).

This way, each developer can store their own configuration.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for compound run configurations. Other users will see the compound run configurations, but they will be **empty** and unusable.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136255/104891).

You need to make the run configuration **Shared**. Then you can add `.idea/runConfigurations/*.xml` files to the version control per [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839).

`workspace.xml` should not be included into the version control.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer? Shared seems to mean "a version of a file is saved in Git and conflicts with local copy on each checkout for other developers".

Comment: @Stepan you can ask developers to use different names for the run configurations that can have conflicts.

Comment: @Stepan JetBrains team has no problem sharing the configurations between the developers, [see here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/.idea/runConfigurations).