# how to commit changes in git with untracked files

Tags: git, gitlab, git-untracked

When creating a project in GitLab, a file that has to be untracked was added (venv). I deleted it with `git rm -r --cached venv`  and when I tried to commit these changes, I receive this message.

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .idea/vcs.xml
        venv/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

How to commit these changes and what was my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You must tell Git, which file you want to commit with `git add` (by the way, that's what the error message says!)

So simple use `git add -A`

> Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching  but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.

(The whole documentation can be consulted [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--A))

After added the files, you must `git commit -am "added newly untracked files"` and `git push` to make the remote repository clear, which files should no longer be tracked.

Comment: This is the wrong answer: the OP wants `venv/` files *not* to be committed, but `git add -A` would add them as they're not currently also ignored.

Comment: @torek But the OP says nothing about `.gitignore`, only about untracking and uncommitting the changes. If you want to ignore it *permanently*, you would just have to add it to the `.gitignore`-file, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

> When creating a project in GitLab, a file that has to be untracked was added (venv). I deleted it with `git rm -r --cached venv` ...

This part is fine.

> [but] when I tried to commit these changes, I receive this message.
>
> ```
> On branch master
> Untracked files:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
>         .idea/vcs.xml
>         venv/
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
> ```

This means you have no changes with respect to the *current commit*.

That is, the `venv/*` are both *untracked* and *not in the current commit*.  The `.idea/vcs.xml` file is likewise untracked and not in the current commit.

That means there's literally nothing to do at this point!

You might, however, wish to make Git *shut up* about these untracked files.  To make *that* happen you should edit the `.gitignore` file to add:

```
.idea/vcs.xml
venv/
```

to it.  Note that at least some files in `.idea` should not be committed, but some say that some files *should* be committed: see [Which files in .idea folder should be tracked by Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43198273/1256452).  The accepted and highest-scored answers (which at the moment are different) both recommend adding and committing `.idea/vcs.xml`, so if you wish to do that, you *should not* list it in your `.gitignore`.

(It is your decision which files to list.  Remember that `.gitignore` does not, by itself, cause a file to be *ignored*.  Instead, it causes Git to *shut up* about a currently-untracked file, and it makes `git add --all` and other en-masse "add" operations *not add* the file.  As such, the name `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-when-they-are-untracked-and-do-not-add-them-when-using-an-en-masse-add-command-either-if-they-are-untracked-at-that-time-because-they-are-supposed-to-stay-untracked-whenever-they-are-currently-untracked` might be more accurate.  But who will type in this file name?)

If you *do* update your `.gitignore` file (or create one), you should then `git add` the `.gitignore`, and now you will have some changes with respect to the *current commit* and will need to make a *new* commit.

Otherwise—if you're content to have Git continue to complain like this—there's really nothing to do.

#### Further discussion

Remember, a *tracked* file is one that is in Git's index / staging-area *right now*.  An *untracked* file is one that is *not* in Git's index / staging-area right now, but is in your working tree.  That's all there is to whether some file is tracked or untracked: it's about what's in the index and your working tree *right now*.

You can, however, *change* which files are in your working tree at any time, by creating, removing, or modifying such files.  You can *change* which files are in Git's index at any time, by running `git add` or, as you did, by running `git rm --cached`.  These actions *change which files are tracked right now*. **They have no effect on any existing commit.**  (It is literally impossible to change any existing commit.)

The set of files that *are* in Git's index *right now* are the set of files that would be in a new commit, if you ran `git commit` *right now*.  That's why you run `git add` or `git rm --cached`: to change the set of files that `git commit` would freeze forever into a new commit.

As you do work, you will run `git add`.  This copies the current version of the working tree file *into* Git's index, so that your *proposed next comimt snapshot* is now updated.  If that was a mistake, you can change the file *back* and run `git add` again.  Or, if—as in this case—`git add`-ing the file at all was the mistake, you can run `git rm --cached` on the file, to remove it from Git's index without affecting the working tree copy.

If the file *wasn't* in Git's index, it was untracked.  If you then *added it to Git's index* it became tracked.  If you then *remove it again* it is back to being untracked.  Until you run `git commit`, each of these updates to Git's index merely changes your *proposed next commit*, not any actual commit.  So make all the changes you like, and when they're *right*, run `git commit` to freeze them into a new commit.